# Login with github in angular2

Tags: github, angular

I have tried to do login with github. I am facing some issue. Here is my code

```
<a href="https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id=my_client_id">
<img src="app/images/signinWithGithub.png">
```

If I click then I am redirecting to my callback location with ?code=asdfsadf345sdf. For example:

```
http://localhost:8080/?code=asdfsadf2345sdf
```

I am using `LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy` due to this I am redirecting to my home page. Now I am unable to get response code

Comment: Usually you solve this by having a backend in Node.js or PHP or something similar. And then you do the actual login logic there.

Comment: Ok thanks. There is no other way to access routeparams value and process login to my app?